# What does 'no implicit conversion of Regexp into String (TypeError)' mean?

Tags: ruby, regex

```
class String
  def digit?
    self.include?(/[0-9]/) 
  end
end

Test.assert_equals "".digit?, false
Test.assert_equals "7".digit?, true
Test.assert_equals " ".digit?, false
```

I have been playing around with regular expressions. Can you tell me how I have made an error? I have tried explicitly converting it to a string but it doesn't work nor do I see why I should have to. Could anyone enlighten me? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matt's answer is good, but it's worth noting that there's some nuance here. Firstly, with the Regexp you have, you're going to match any string that contains any digit:

```
class String
  def digit?
    match(/[0-9]/) 
  end
end

"foo1bar".digit? # => #<MatchData "1">
```

If you want to match a single digit you'll want to use anchors—`\A` and `\z` for the start and end of the string, respectively—and while we're at it, you might as well use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`, ergo `/\A\d\z/`. If you want to match one or more digits, use the `+` quantifier: `/\A\d+\z/`.

Finally, `match` might be overkill here. I suggest using the `=~` operator:

```
class String
  def digit?
    self =~ /\A\d\z/
  end

  def digits?
    self =~ /\A\d+\z/
  end
end

"foo123bar".digit?  # => nil
"1".digit?          # => 0
"123".digit?        # => nil

"foo123bar".digits? # => nil
"1".digits?         # => 0
"123".digits?       # => 0
```

Answer (score 6):

`include?` expects a string as documented [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F). It seems like you were looking for [`match`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-match).